# Android source code location

Tags: android, repository

I created a directory "Test". 
Did below steps:

> repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest
>
> repo sync

When sync was complete, there were no files in my "Test" directory.
Can somebody help me with source code location?

Answer (score 0):

double check with the online tutorial [Downloading the Source](http://source.android.com/source/downloading.html). 
1. was your network connection OK?
2. Did you cd to Test?
3. try to repo a branch
4. use "find" command to search